# Can't build query string using get_compiled_select() method of node-querybuilder

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm a new to **node.js** and using node-querybuilder for making api request to database. All is working good but when trying to use **get_compiled_select()** method of **node-querybuilder** nodejs package, it's giving a error like this.

**Error:**

```
Caught error: ReferenceError: from_array is not defined
```

What I've tried code, is given below -

**NodeJs Code:**

```
try {  
    var sql = db.select(["u.name"]).from("users u").get_compiled_select();
    console.log(sql);
}
catch(err) {
    console.error("Caught error: "  + err);
}
```

Sorry for my bad English.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: On which line you are getting `ReferenceError` ? Or can you share error stack trace?

Comment: I'm getting error in this try..catch block of code.